# Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters work properly in spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE, but JSESSIONID is overwritten in different browsers

Tags: security, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, jsessionid

The path(www.mywebsite.com/admin/) is allowed to be accessed by only ROLE_ADMIN, and other paths(www.mywebsite.com/....) is allowed to be accessed by ROLE_USER or ROLE_ANONYMOUS.
I have two different classes(extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) for this policy and they are successfully executed.

Problem is 
when I log on as ROLE_ADMIN in www.mywebsite.com/admin/.. in one browser, and then I log on as ROLE_USER in www.mywebsite.com/... in DIFFERENT browser, and then I go to www.mywebsite.com/admin/.., my admin session information(ROLE_ADMIN) is overwritten by the user session information, so I get the ERROR (Permission Deny).

My understanding is both of classes(extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) use the same session name(JSESSIONID), so the ROLE_USER information overwrites the ROLE_ADMIN information even though in different browsers.

If I don't use Spring Security, I will provide two different session names for ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER and I can use both roles at the same time in different browsers.

Is there any way to solve this problem with Spring Security? Please, give me good ideas.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it a different browser (i.e. firefox and chrome) or a different window/tab. In the latter case you are basically overriding the session information and that is just how browsers work is it the first then it shouldn't happen and you have another issue at hand.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but you can try with add

disable-url-rewriting="true"

in  this tag in spring-security.xml file

```html
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"  disable-url-rewriting="true" >
```

if doesn't work...Please read this article i think it helps you.

**http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session**